# How do I select hardware OpenGL rendering for MATLAB on Linux

Tags: matlab

When I start matlab on my linux machine, I get the notice, "MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering." Once it starts up, if I try `opengl hardware` I get the message that I can't switch at runtime. How do I enable hardware rendering as simply as possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first answers that turn up when searching for an answer to this question lead me to try and solve non-existent problems with the opengl libraries on my system. Other solutions proposed setting the option in the startup.m or matlabrc.m files, which didn't work for me.

It took way too long to find what seems like should be the first answer to pop up: Start matlab from the terminal with `matlab -nosoftwareopengl`.

Once it starts, running `opengl info` in matlab shows that hardware rendering is indeed selected.

Comment: Hardware opengl works perfectly with my nvidia card (with the nvidia driver installed)  after adding `-nosoftwareopengl`. The nvidia card runs independently from the on-board Intel video card (using Prime Render Offload).

Hardware opengl failed with the default integrated intel video however, with error
`libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and `libGL error: failed to load driver: iris`
It is true, iris is not installed. Never heard of it, why does it want it?

Answer (score 2):

In my Ubuntu 20.04 I solved it with:

```
export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965
```

This line can also be added to the /etc/environment file so that you don't have to do it again and again.

Answer (score -5):

Try these code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9

sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
```

This will resolve the issue.